# Bigquery - schedule stored procedure not working anymore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

recently there was a change in Bigquery UI and it seems that is no longer possible to schedule a stored procedure to execute automatically.

Using the UI, just keeps asking to insert a destination table. If I put a dummy table, the schedule is created but then when tries to execute just throws an error saying that we can't have a destination table when executing a stored procedure.

Is anyone having this issue and has any kind of workaround ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there were already few question with same issue here on SO - switch to the old interface by pressing "Hide preview features" at the top of the screen.

Comment: That solved the issue. Many thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can opt out of the preview features by clicking the [Hide Preview Features](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/work-warp-speed-bigquery-ui) button in the top bar of the UI.

This is a known issue that the BigQuery engineering team is already aware of and are rolling the fix for it soon. You can follow their progress on this [Public Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/176994053)